# Elasticsearch how to override an existing field in a pipeline?

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, logstash, elastic-stack, filebeat

In my **Pipeline** I extract a *timestamp*.
I would like to override the existing *timestamp* field.
How would I do this?

Pipeline:

```
{
  "description": "...",
  "processors": [
    {
      "grok": {
        "field": "message",
        "patterns": [
          "{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp2}"
        ],
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like *timestamp2* to override the original timestamp field.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply override the field name like this:

```
"description": "...",
"processors": [
  {
    "grok": {
      "field": "message",
      "patterns": [
        "%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601:timestamp}"    <--- use timestamp here instead of timestamp2
      ]
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: Ahh Thanks, I wrongly assumed they would form a list. I used a date processor for the timestamp and it worked and I used this method to override my message.